# installing Abbyy ocr server on Amazon -- incompatible GLIBC

Tags: amazon-ec2, glibc

I'm trying to run ABBYY server (version 10) in Amazon EC2 instance.

At home, I realized that Abbyy requires a different (lower) GLIBC version than the one that comes with Ubuntu 12.04.

It installed successfully on Ubuntu 11 or 10.

But currently Amazon officially provides only Ubuntu 12 & 13.

So - How can I install this program on Amazon?

```
I understand that it's not possible to install EC2 from an ISO image
```

1) Can I downgrade GLIBC6? (nothing else will be running on that instance)

2) is there a way to install a lower version of ubuntu on EC2?

3) is there another way to run abbyy server on amazon today ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i discovered that there are "old" images for use in ubuntu's own website.
sorry, but i don't have the link here.

Answer (score 0):

They are very guilty of not keeping these instances current.  Thus the best thing to do is to create your own base image and install the ABBYY engine yourself.  Also keep in mind that because OCR is a CPU and memory hog i've found the current instances they have created are not supporting a typical OCR load.  I often think these instances are for marketing only, and to do real OCR you need to build your own.